# Apache2 does not log errors

Tags: php, linux, apache, ubuntu, error-log

I have a challenge which hopefully can conquered with the help of the SO community...

My apache server will not log errors, PHP nor HTTP.

Here is the config to one of my sites:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName website
ServerAdmin webmaster@website.com

DocumentRoot /var/www/website
<Directory /var/www/website>
    Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride ALL
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/website.error.log

# Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
# alert, emerg.
LogLevel warn

CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/website.access.log combined
```

It was all working before but now it doesn't log, I've tried deleting the log file in /var/log/apache2 and restarting apache.  It does recreate the log file, but does not write to it.

The next thing I did was give full permissions and ownership to the apache user. When that didn't work I gave permissions to everyone to read and write.  That still did not work.

In the mean time of all that, I even made a change to the php.ini file and set php to write it's errors to a separate file.

I've done nothing to default settings of apache.  I'm just not sure what happened to apache...

Answer (score 0):

Its loglevel set to warn. Maybe there were no warn level events occuring. Change it to debug and retry please.